# How to set server variable $SCRIPT_NAME in php

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

My php application is running in Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu).

`php-fpm` is active.

There is a problem loading php application. It returning `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` as `"php5.fcgi"` instead of `"index.php"`.

Where do i set value for this variable? could it be configured in `.htaccess` file?

`SCRIPT_NAME` is taken from the exact URI after the domain name. But is always returning value as `"php5.fcgi"`

Comment: May this link will help you :- http://emspace.com.au/article/nginx-rewrite-rules-pathinfo-and-scriptname

Answer (score 0):

```
SCRIPT_FILENAME=$PATH_TRANSLATED
export SCRIPT_FILENAME
```

php5.fcgi :

```
!/bin/bash
PHPRC=$PWD/../etc/php5
export PHPRC
umask 022
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=99999
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
SCRIPT_FILENAME=$PATH_TRANSLATED
export SCRIPT_FILENAME
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

Comment: Please edit your php5.fcgi, to ensure the **SCRIPT_FILENAME=$PATH_TRANSLATED
export SCRIPT_FILENAME** is there